# R-Count and list the maximum count row by row

Tags: r, max

I have a matrix:

```
count <- matrix(c("a","a","a","b","b","i","i","b","a","a","g","i","a","g","g","g"),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  a    a    a   b
[2,]  b    i    i   b
[3,]  a    a    g   i
[4,]  a    g    g   g
```

I wanted to find the value(s) which occurs the maximum number of times in each row and assign those values to another column, to look like this:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,count]
[1,]  a    a    a   b      a
[2,]  b    i    i   b      b & i
[3,]  a    h    h   i      h
[4,]  a    g    g   g      g
```

I tried using `apply(count,1,max)` but did not work out.

Comment: Could you provide some more context for how you define "maximum"?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen which is for each of the row, I need to do a counting of what alphabet appears to be the most and list it out.

Answer (score 5):

Your input and output data don't match, but I think this is what you are after:

```
count <- matrix(c("a","a","a","b","b","i","i","b",
                  "a","a","g","i","a","g","g","g"),
                ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
count
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b" 
# [2,] "b"  "i"  "i"  "b" 
# [3,] "a"  "a"  "g"  "i" 
# [4,] "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"    

cbind(count,
      apply(count, 1, function(x) {
        z <- table(x)
        paste(names(z)[z == max(z)], collapse = " & ")
      }))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]   
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "a"    
# [2,] "b"  "i"  "i"  "b"  "b & i"
# [3,] "a"  "a"  "g"  "i"  "a"    
# [4,] "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "g"
```

Answer (score -1):

Thy this:
cbind(count,apply(count,1,myfun<-function(x) { a<-table(x);b<-rownames(a)[a==max(a)];b<-paste(b,collapse=" & ");return(b) } )  )

Comment: ha,sorry,write wrong number in function apply. "apply(count,1,...)" not "apply(count,2,...)"